# Enabling nested virtualization with virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a main Win 7 machine with virtualbox, an a Linux Mint vm, I want to test some docker containers in the vm, and I am getting some errors saying there's no KVM support.

Settings:

[VM Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvtJG.png)

[VM Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUaEj.png)

[Speccy CPU Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZwGW.png)

```
vm@vm ~ $ sudo kvm-ok 
[sudo] password for vm: 
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used


vm@vm ~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz
stepping    : 7
cpu MHz     : 3292.522
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm
bugs        :
bogomips    : 6585.04
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK containers and Docker don't require virtualization. On Linux they are regular processes running in a "bubble". On non-Linux platforms the Docker support may come as some kind of virtual machine with  a Linux kernel but on Linux it uses standard system capabilities. So since your VM is already a Linux system you can install Docker directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox 6 now comes with
[nested virtualisation support](https://blogs.oracle.com/virtualization/oracle-vm-virtualbox-60-now-available)

But as @harrymc says, its not required to run docker within a linux VM.

It *is* required for windows to run docker, and if your virtualisation sw does not support nested VT-X it will fail for *windows* guests.

VBox 5.x did not support nested vt-x, so a windows guest would not support docker, although a linux guest is ok.

As your case is a linux guest I think you have a different issue, perhaps you could provide o/s details along with the actual errors you're getting trying to start docker. Initially I would see what errors [hello-world](https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world) gives.

Answer (score 0):

I quote from
[Does Docker Need Hardware Virtualization?](https://www.unixtutorial.org/does-docker-need-hardware-virtualization)

> The short answer is: **no**. Docker needs a 64-bit Linux OS running a modern enough kernel to operate properly. Which means if that what you have happily running on your hardware without hw virtualization support, it will be plenty enough for Docker.

There is no reason to test for nested virtualization.
In any case, Linux on Windows does not play well with nested virtualization,
so the KVM error should not block you from using Docker.

Docker should run in your Linux VM. If it does not, then there is another
error which does not relate to this post.